# Scheme program to get average not recognizing last number

Tags: scheme

I've created this super simple program to take a list from the console and return the average. For whatever reason I always get an error message saying the last number of the list is not a number. Here's my code:

```
(define getline (lambda () 
              (read-line (current-input-port))
            )
    )

(define getlist (lambda () 
              (let ((input (getline)))
                (if (not (equal? input "end")) 
                    (cons input (getlist)) 
                    ' ()
                    )
                )
              )
  )
(define x (getlist))

(define (sum x)
(if (null? x)
    0
    (+ (car x) (sum (cdr x)))))

(define (average x)
(/ (sum x) (length x)))

(display (average x) (current-output-port))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what scheme implementation you're using, but `read-line` functions usually return a string. You have to convert those strings to numbers first to be able to add them:

```
(define x (map string->number (getlist)))
```

or else

```
(define (sum x)
  (if (null? x)
      0
      (+ (string->number (car x)) (sum (cdr x)))))
```

or something else along those lines.